# How to configure batches for LSTM with Marwil in rllib

Tags: lstm, reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

I'm trying to train an lstm policy using Marwil in rllib. I could not find any examples for how to set up the batches for this problem. I train a marwil model just fine if it does not have an lstm component by using the instructions here.

https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-offline.html

However, when I try to add an lstm component, I get an error about

"seq_lens tensor must be given if state inputs are defined"

which I take it to mean implies I need to pass it a sequence of RNN lengths. Fair enough, I define

prev_actions -> list of twenty past actions for all N points in the episode
prev_rewards -> list of twenty past rewards for all N points in the episode
prev_observations -> list of twenty past observations for all N points in the episode
seq_lens -> [20, 20, 20, ..., 20] for all N points in the episode

in the batch builder API, but once I try to run the Marwil trainer I still get the error

seq_lens tensor must be given if state inputs are defined

Does someone have any insight into this?

Thanks!